# KeystoneJS in Production

Tags: node.js, keystonejs

I have my app stored at `appdir/app/` and then in `appdir/bin` I have the start and stop files for my keystone app.

To get keystone to work on my server it has to listen on a port number so i'm trying to set the port env variable in my file and i'm trying to do it in my start file. Heres what I have:

```
#!/bin/sh

export NODE_ENV=production
export PORT=24633

forever start -a -l /XXX/logs/log.log -o /XXXlogs/out.log -e /XXX/logs/err.log /XXX/app/keystone.js
```

It works without any errors, however it's not working with the port number specified. Am I overlooking something here or is the route i'm taking wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Did you set the port in keystone.js ?

```
keystone.init({
  ...
  port: process.env.PORT,
  ...
});
```